# Get the length of time the iPhone was locked

Tags: ios

How would I get the length of time a phone was locked if I wanted to use it to increment a timer progress view when the phone was resumed, or schedule a notification to fire when the phone was still locked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the UIApplicationDelegate method [applicationWillResignActive:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive:) and [applicationDidBecomeActive:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidBecomeActive:).

You will have to store the current time when the former is called and calculate the difference when the latter is called. Specifically, in your application delegate:

```
#define TIMESTAMP_KEY @"timestamp"

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
   NSInteger *timestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
   [[NSUserDefault standardUserDefaults] setInteger:timestamp forKey:TIMESTAMP_KEY];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
   NSInteger *newTimestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
   NSInteger *oldTimestamp = [[NSUserDefault standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:TIMESTAMP_KEY];
   NSInteger *secondsPassed = newTimestamp - oldTimestamp;
   // Now you can resynch your timer with the secondsPassed 
}
```